# create sqlite database in local store on blackberry

Tags: database, blackberry, store

I am trying to create a database in the device storage of a BlackBerry simulator. In the 9300 simulator, I find the folder databases but not the file.sqlite. How can I find this file?

I use

```
URI myURI = URI.create("/store/home/user/databases/database.sqlite"); 
DatabaseFactory.create(myURI);
```

Comment: Try to log exceptions. I think there is one that will give you a hint what is the problem.

Comment: DatabaseIOException
[0.0] File system not ready

Answer (score 1):

I edited this page

> You must simulate the SDCard; see the below link(see the bottom of that page) "Run the sample application(see 3rd point)"

and this line also provided there

> Create the database on a media card instead of in device memory. Only certain BlackBerry® devices support storing an SQLite database in device memory.

[For run the SQLITEDEMO in simulator you must simulate sdcard;](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29299/SQLite_sample_app_1554292_11.jsp)